# markers won't show up on google map(kotlin-android)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, google-maps-markers, kotlin-flow

first of all sorry if my grammar is bad
also i am not professional in android programming

here's the problem:
i call api to get some data(including latitude and longitude of stores)
i enabled paging to get all data
and pass the latitude and longitude of stores to my marker
now when i run the app, i can see my exact location on the map but there is no marker around me
here is my code :

my response class :

```
data class ResponseGetStores(
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: ApiData?,
    @SerializedName("isSuccess")
    val isSuccess: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("statusCode")
    val statusCode: String?,
    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String?
)

data class ApiData(
    @SerializedName("items")
    val items: List<ApiItem>?,
    @SerializedName("pageNumber")
    val pageNumber: Int?,
    @SerializedName("totalPages")
    val totalPages: Int?,
    @SerializedName("totalCount")
    val totalCount: Int?,
    @SerializedName("hasPreviousPage")
    val hasPreviousPage: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("hasNextPage")
    val hasNextPage: Boolean?
)

data class ApiItem(
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("externalStoreId")
    val externalStoreId: String?,
    @SerializedName("address")
    val address: String?,
    @SerializedName("category")
    val category: String?,
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    val latitude: Double?,
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    val longitude: Double?,
    @SerializedName("cashbackSystemPercent")
    val cashbackSystemPercent: Double?,
    @SerializedName("crypto")
    val crypto: String?,
    @SerializedName("distance")
    val distance: Double?, // null bood
    @SerializedName("poses")
    val poses: List<String>?, // null bood
    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    val createdAt: String?,
    @SerializedName("important")
    val important: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("cashbackSystem")
    val cashbackSystem: CashbackSystem?,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int
)

data class CashbackSystem(
    val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("englishName")
    val englishName: String?,
    val id: Int?,
    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    val createdAt: String?
)
```

my paging class :

```
class StorePagingClass(private val repository: StoreRepository) :
    PagingSource<Int, ApiItem>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, ApiItem> {

        return try {
            val page = params.key ?: 1
            val response = repository.getStores(page)

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val data = response.body()?.data?.items ?: emptyList()

                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = data,
                    prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1,
                    nextKey = if (data.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
                )
            } else {

                LoadResult.Error(Exception("Failed to load data"))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, ApiItem>): Int? {
        return null
    }
}
```

my viewmodel :

```
class GoogleMapViewModel(private val repository: StoreRepository): ViewModel() {

    val storelist = Pager(PagingConfig(2)){
        StorePagingClass(repository)
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            storelist.collect { pagingData ->
                Log.d("GoogleMapViewModel", "paging data received")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my activity :

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
    private lateinit var locViewModel: GoogleMapViewModel
    private lateinit var locationManager: LocationManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val apiService = RetrofitStore.zarinpalStore
        val storeRepository = StoreRepository(apiService)
        val factory = GoogleMapViewModelFactory(storeRepository)

        //LocationManager
        locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)


        locViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(GoogleMapViewModel::class.java)



    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.uiSettings.apply {
            isZoomControlsEnabled = true
            isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
            isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
        }
        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        if (checkPermission()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {
                val lastloc = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).lastLocation
                lastloc.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val userloc = task.result
                        val userlat = userloc.latitude
                        val userlong = userloc.longitude
                        val userexactloc = LatLng(userlat, userlong)

                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userexactloc, 17f))





                        lifecycleScope.launch {


                            locViewModel.storelist.collectLatest{ pagingData ->




                                    pagingData.map {
                                        val latitude1 = it.latitude ?: 0.0
                                        val longitude1 = it.longitude ?: 0.0

                                        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                                            .position(
                                                LatLng(
                                                    latitude1,
                                                    longitude1
                                                )
                                            )
                                            .title(it.name)
                                            .icon(

                                                vectorToBitmap(
                                                    this@MapsActivity,
                                                    R.drawable.custommark
                                                )
                                            )
                                            .visible(false)


                                        val marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)

                                        val circle = mMap.addCircle(
                                            CircleOptions()
                                                .center(userexactloc)
                                                .radius(35000.00)
                                        )
                                        val distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(
                                            userexactloc,
                                            LatLng(latitude1, longitude1)
                                        )


                                        if (distance < circle.radius) {
                                            marker?.isVisible = true
                                        } else {
                                            // Handle when the distance is more than the circle radius
                                        }

                                     }

                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }



    private fun checkPermission(): Boolean {
        return !(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)


    }

    private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        return (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
        )


    }

    fun vectorToBitmap(context: Context, @DrawableRes vectorResId: Int): BitmapDescriptor {
        val vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId)
        vectorDrawable?.setBounds(
            0,
            0,
            vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth,
            vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight
        )
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            vectorDrawable?.intrinsicWidth ?: 0,
            vectorDrawable?.intrinsicHeight ?: 0,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        vectorDrawable?.draw(canvas)
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    }

}
```

for this part in my viewmodel :
Log.d("GoogleMapViewModel", "paging data received")

i am getting this message when run the app

also i should mention that i am sure that there are stores near me (less than 35 km) because before enabling paging, i could see some markers around me

i think the problem comes from my activity

Comment: Are you seeing the code in your activity being updated after the pagingData is received? Meaning, if you debug it, do you see the logic stopping there?

Comment: @tomerpacific 
val userexactloc = LatLng(userlat, userlong)
this is the the last code that execute in debugger

i get the latitude and longitude of user but logic will stop there

Comment: So I would check why your paging data that is being received is not updating here. Debug the flow that is related to it.